# Sync Google Sheet with Microsoft Form Responses

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets, microsoft-forms

I have a Microsoft form and the responses are recorded in an Excel file. I want to sync this Excel file with a Google sheet to do some calculations there. Sometimes, some formulas break the connection between the Excel file and Microsoft form and new responses do not appear. That's why I prefer to do the calculations in a Google sheet. However, I want to avoid copying the new responses every time. I need to sync them.

Comment: Maybe you could use OneDrive's API paired with Google AppsScript to do this, but you would need a computer (or VM in a server, or Docker container in a server, or EC2 instance, or whatever) constantly running this request to transfer the data.

Comment: Are you able to use Google Forms instead? It has built-in features to write directly to a Google Sheet.

Comment: You could do your Excel calculations in a separate workbook, and use the responses file as a data source connection only (to avoid breaking that connection).

Comment: Is one of [these methods](https://www.makeuseof.com/sync-microsoft-forms-to-excel/) usable in your case?

Comment: This might help **[Record Microsoft Form responses in a Google Sheet.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Flow-Forms-to-Google-Sheet/td-p/426174)**